# Can I create menu templates with html and css

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to organize an html website such that the design is in one file and the contents are in another.

For example, we need a website in 2 languages. Is it possible to store the menu items with html somewhere so that we would have to alter them only once and not in an html file of each page?

A similar approach could potentially keep the website frame the same, but just change the text based on contents of another file? Or is this not meant to be done in a static html website (the kind that could be stored and viewed on github).

Thanks! (I'm not an experienced web designer, I would appreciate any helpful links if you understand my question.)

Comment: Learn about PHP or Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this would be using PHP.

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

with something like this.

Comment: Why the best way is using php? Why not any other server-side language? Or why not ajax for example if the user wants to use client-side without any server-side language?

Comment: Much better, removed my down-vote :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.
The MVC structure makes it possible but you have to use a Server-Sided language like PHP or C# (with ASP.NET).

OR

By using JavaScript, a Server-side language and a .json file.
When the page is loaded, you request the json encoded corresponding datas to the server with AJAX and you fill the HTML tags with JS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these options.